# álbum de fotos com HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5

> Eu tenho uma pasta no site chamada **FOTOS** , ao clicar na pasta **FOTOS** eu pensei em colocar vários `< article >` dividindo cada álbum de fotos tipo:

```
< article > album de fotos 01 < article >
< article > album de fotos 02 < article >
< article > album de fotos 03 < article >
```

Cada álbum desses eu vou colocar mais ou menos 10 a 15 fotos em miniaturas, `200px` por `200px`.
Alguém pode me ajudar para que ao clicar em cada foto elas abrissem num tamanho maior?

Se possível só com html e css,  mais aceito outras sugestões também.. 
**ta ai meu codigo**

```
<article ="album-foto01">

 <ul>

    <li id="foto01"><img src="imagem.jpg"></li>      
    <li id="foto02"><img src="imagem1.jpg"></li>         
    <li id="foto03"><img src="imagem2.jpg"></li>
    <li id="foto04"> <img src="imagem3.jpg"></li>
    <li id="foto05"> <img src="imagem4.jpg"></li>
    <li id="foto06"> <img src="imagem5.jpg"></li>

<ul/>
```

```
<ul>
    <li id="foto01"><img src="imagen.jpg"></li>      
    <li id="foto02"><img src="imagem1.jpg"></li>         
    <li id="foto03"><img src="imagem2.jpg"></li>
    <li id="foto04"> <img src="imagem3.jpg"></li>
    <li id="foto05"> <img src="imagem4.jpg"></li>
    <li id="foto06"> <img src="imagem5.jpg"></li>

<ul/>
```

Comment: Você já tem algum código? Poste por favor.

Comment: postei o codigo na pergunta e mais ou meno assim

Comment: mas você já tentou algo com CSS ou Javascript?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero NÃO  eu ate o momento so fiz isso ai mesmo

Comment: As imagens são quadradas ou só a miniatura?

Comment: @dvd na verdade são imagem normais quadradas ,mais pensei em usar css para diminuir elas  . vou deixar elas 200px por 200px e tipo  ao clicar nela ela se abrir maior  mais que eu podece mudar elas  sabe  igual as imagens do face book quando clicamos para visualizar maior  com o botaozinho de mudar as fotos

Comment: Aqui no site tem varias respostas que podem te auxiliar se você pesquisar algo como, zoom imagem, aumentar imagem etc..

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Aumentar imagem quando o usuário clicar em JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106970/aumentar-imagem-quando-o-usu%c3%a1rio-clicar-em-js)

Comment: Outra solução que poderia te dar uma ideia mas não é no "click" e sim ao passar o mouse em cima: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246447/88202

Comment: @CaiqueRomero a ideia de usar o hover e legal e quase isso  que to querrendo  vou  dar uma olhada no link aki

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi vc quer uma "Galeria de Fotos", e SIM, é possível só com HTML e CSS. Vou montar um exemplo básico pra vc, me da um tempo e te respondo.

Comment: @hugocsl  agradeço !

Comment: Tem varios plugins de js para fazer isso....agora a tag `article` nao serve para mostrar fotos e sim artigos de texto, com título, header, paragrafo, essas coisas. Semanticamente está incorreto a maneira que vc montou. Você poderia utilizar a tag `ul`.

Comment: @KarlZillner na verdade foi por que eu esquecir decolocar a < ul >,
e os < article > e para separar cada album

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segue aqui um modelo bem simples que pode te servir de exemplo e para estudos.

O principal é que ele usa a pseudo classe `:target` para mudar a opacidade das imagens e mostra-las em tamanho grande. Outra coisa é que ele usa *"ancoras"* para fazer a navegação entre uma imagem e outra.

No exemplo exite uma `<ul>` com a miniaturas, e clicando nela com o `:target` a imagem grande aparece. *(Na verdade o que aparece é um "bloco" com todos os elementos dentro, imagem grande e botões de navegação. Então quando vc muda de uma imagem para outra na verdade vc está trocando também os btns de navegação, só que vc não percebe essa troca visualmente por ser um elemento no mesmo lugar do outro. Só a imagem que vc percebe pq são diferentes.)*

Agora vamos ao que interessa o código!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.lbox {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
ul {
    width: 800px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
.min {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.lbox:target {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.7);
}
.box-img {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 150px auto;
}
.btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#prev {
    left: 5%;
    top: 45%;
}
#next {
    right: 5%;
    top: 45%;
}
#close {
    top: 0;
    right: 2px;
}
.box-img img {
    opacity: 0;
}

.lbox:target .box-img img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 250ms linear;    
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#img1"><img src="http://placecage.com/800/400" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#img2"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/800/400" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#img3"><img src="http://placecage.com/800/401" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#img4"><img src="http://fillmurray.com/800/401" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="lbox" id="img1">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img4" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="http://placecage.com/800/400" alt="">
        <a href="#img2" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lbox" id="img2">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img1" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/800/400" alt="">
        <a href="#img3" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lbox" id="img3">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img2" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="http://placecage.com/800/401" alt="">
        <a href="#img4" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lbox" id="img4">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img3" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/800/401" alt="">
        <a href="#img1" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OBS1:** Alguns valores estão em PX então ele não está 100% responsivo, mas isso vc mesmo pode arrumar rss

**OBS2:** Ele não é dinâmico, para cada imagem vc vai ter que criar o bloco `.lbox` novo e fazer a "ancoragem dos links"

**OBS3:** [Link de referencia do exemplo que usei.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiS1hxKfFyY)

Comment: e isso ai  exatamente  isso que eu tava  procurando !
muito obrigado por tirar um tempinho pra min ajudar.  
esse canal  do link que você mandou eu  conheço  e sou inscrito mais nem me passou pela cabeça procurar  no canal

Comment: Danilo esse modelo do link eu conhecia de longa data, mas nunca tinha aplicado em nada, não dessa forma. Agora tanta deixar ele responsivo, não vai ser difícil acredito! Boa sorte com o projeto.